# Databricks update files which name is on DataFrame

Tags: azure-databricks, dbutils

I have a DataFrame like:

```
input_df = self.spark.createDataFrame(
            data=[
                ("01", "file_name_1"),
                ("02", "file_name_2"),
                ("05", "file_name_5"),
            ],
            schema=(
                "RECORD_ID: string, FILE_NAME: string"
            ),
        )
```

I have a folder `/mnt/data/project/integration_test/` with the following files

```
file_name_1.json
file_name_2.json
file_name_3.json
file_name_4.json
```

#### I want to update those json files that are on the `input_df`

I thought the process would be:

- Delete json which name appears on `input_df`
- Save each row `input_df` as individual json (I already solved this)

The final files on `/mnt/data/project/integration_test/` would be:

```
file_name_1.json (updated)
file_name_2.json (updated)
file_name_3.json 
file_name_4.json
file_name_5.json (created new)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use Pandas and then iterate the file name and check if the file exists .

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
input_df = spark.createDataFrame(
            data=[
                ("01", "test"),
                ("02", "test1"),
                ("05", "test2"),
            ],
            schema=(
                "RECORD_ID: string, FILE_NAME: string"
            ),
        )
display(input_df)
pandas_df = input_df.toPandas()
for index,row in pandas_df.iterrows():
    print(row['FILE_NAME'])
    if os.path.isfile(PATH):
       print("File exists ")
       // Update the existing file 
    else:
       print("File NOT exists ")   
       //Create a new file
```